# I need a service to call a method in another class. What would it be?

Tags: android, android-service

Hi and thanks for your help.

here is my scenario.

I need to schedule alarms via an AlarmManager.

The scheduling of the alarms needs to happen both

1. when the app is running
2. and when the phone is switched on. In this scenario I start a Service via a BOOT receiver.

Now, in booth cases I need to call a method of some class to pass it the event I want to schedule.

Considered that

- the method would take an the Event object I created as input
- the method needs to be called both by the running activity or by the service, depending on the situation

my question is: **what kind of object (that would contain the above mentioned method) would I  need to create?**

an Activity? don't think so...

a Service? don't think so

Please what could I use?

Comment: What would that method need to do, exactly? If the whole idea is just to persist the event, you could use a ContentProvider.

Comment: @ivagarz thanks ivagarz, the method would set an alarm via an AlarmManager. IMHO I do not think a ContentProvider would be a solution.

Comment: Seems like you would want to send an Intent to a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @goto10 thanks goto10 but that would't work because I need to pass an object to that method (a non parceable one).

Comment: Any particular reason you can't encapsulate the necessary data the object (like the datetime schedule for the alarm) and just send data and recreate the object from the serialized data from the intent?

Comment: Parcelable is just a serialization standard. If you are creating the object yourself you should be able to make a parcelable version. If it includes heavy objects like sounds or images they can be stored on the SD card and reconstituted in the receiver or, as suggested earlier, served up by a ContentProvider.

Comment: @Selecsosi definitely I could, but would that be the best solution? I was looking for something more simple...

Comment: why could you not use a foreground service which the application binds to and can invoke methods on?

Comment: @o0rebelious0o because there might not be a foreground service, the Service I use is started by the BOOT_COMPLETED intent

Comment: I had misunderstood your question.  In that case, you definitely want a broadcast receiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already implemented something like that. In my application a `BroadcastReceiver` receives the alarm (an `Intent`) and then an activty is started passing some parameters.

This is a piece of my code. Let it be the section abuot passing and receiving parameters

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
    int answerType = i.getExtras().getInt("answerType");
    Intent intent = new Intent(arg0, ReminderActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", i.getExtras().getInt("id")); 
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    c.startActivity(intent);
   }

}
```

I writed a class named ReminderManger that includes a method for setting Alarm. Something like this:

```
public void setAlarm(Notification n){

        Intent intent = new Intent(reminderContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("id",n.ID); 
        intent.putExtra("answerType",n.AnswerType);

        int execTimeInt = Integer.parseInt(n.ExecutionTimespan); 
        long execTime = (long)execTimeInt;
        execTime = execTime*1000;

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(reminderContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        currentPendingIntent = pendingIntent;
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)reminderContext.getSystemService(reminderContext.ALARM_SERVICE);
        currentAlarm = alarmManager;

        if(execTime < System.currentTimeMillis() && System.currentTimeMillis() - execTime < NOTIFICATION_THRESHOLD)
        {
            alarmRunning = true;
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+EXECUTION_DELAY,pendingIntent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks Joseph82 but I do not need to start an Activty, I just need somewhere to put my alarmmanager and a method to call it passing an object

Comment: After your BroadcastReceiver receives the Intent, you can do anything you want

Comment: @Lisa my class AlarmManager is only a class, not an Activity. YOu just need that somewhere the setAlarm method is executed. Then the Alarm will do the rest. When you have intercepted the intent inside the BroadcastReceiver you can do(as said) anythink you want (for exmple I call an Activty)